# What is definition of order topology?

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

I am doing self study of topology, the book I am following has used term order topology in problems and few theorems. What is order topology? Kindly give explanation with some examples that will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which book is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a set $X$ has a linear order $<$ (with the convention that $x < x$ never holds, we use $\le$ for those linear orders) we can define a topology on $X$ by the defining a subbase $\mathcal{S}=\{L(x), U(x): x \in X\}$ where we define the lower set $L(x)=\{y \in X: y < x\}$ and the upper set $U(x) = \{y \in X: y > x\}$.

In other words, by definition the order topology on $X$ is the smallest (in inclusion) topology in which all sets of the form $L(x)$ and $U(x)$ are open. This is mostly inspired by how the topology on standard ordered sets like $\Bbb R, \Bbb Q$ is defined. Note that any open interval $(x,y)=\{z \in Z: x < z \land z < y\}$ is also open in $X$, as the intersection of two open sets $L(y) \cap U(x)$. But if $X$ has a maximal element, like $1$ in $[0,1]$, it will never lie in any open interval (there is no right-hand endpoint that is strictly bigger than it) but it will be in open sets of the form $(a,1]=U(a)$ and these sets then form its local base of neighbourhoods.

So the standard base for the order topology is all open intervals $(x,y), x,y \in X$ plus all sets $[m,x)=L(x), x \in X$ when $m$ has a minimum $m$, plus all sets $(x,M], x \in X$ when $X$ has a maximum $M$. (If we have neither we don't need such sets in our topology). All open sets are then the unions of basic open sets, as always.

Munkres (2nd ed.) introduces this topology in §14, p.85 and Engelking introduces the topology in Exercise 1.7.4. In papers they're often abbreviated as LOTS (linearly ordered topological space). There is quite a rich theory surrounding them, and many special theorems that hold for them.

Comment: What is simple order relation (mentioned in Munkres) ?

Comment: @HarryWilliamson A *simply ordered* set is what I call a linearly ordered one: if $x,y \in X$, $x=y$ or $x < y$ or $x>y$ must hold. (Otherwise it's a "partial order"). Total order is sometimes also used.

Comment: Can you give example of simply ordered set and partial order  ?

Comment: @HarryWilliamson The integers $\mathbb{Z}$ in their ususal order is one, and the power set and subset-relation is a partial order. Or $\mathbb{Z}$ with $a \le b$ iff $a$ divides $b$, etc, Read par. 3 in Munkres where he introduces orders. Read books from the start, or you miss all the definitions, doesn't his book have an index?

Comment: The index in the Pearson International Edition of Munkres is next to useless, I can tell from experience.

Answer (score 3):

The order topology is the natural generalisation of the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Given a partially ordered set $(X,\leq)$ with more than one element you can define a topology on $X$ having as sub-basis sets of the form 
$$
(-\infty,x_1)=\{x\in X|\; x<x_1\}\\
(x_1,\infty)=\{x\in X|\; x_1<x\}\\
$$

Examples include, as stated, $\mathbb{R}$ (and $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q},$ I guess) in the usual topology.

Given any set $Y,$ let $X=\mathcal{P}(Y)$ denote its power set. Then, there is a natural ordering on $X$ given by set inclusion and so, you get a topology on the power set, where a set $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if for every $A\in U,$ there exists $A_0$ and $A_1$ such that $A_0\subsetneq U\subsetneq A_1$ and for any set $A_0\subsetneq B\subsetneq A_1,$ we have $B$ in $U$.

A last example that Munkres likes to use is $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the lexicographical ordering. Here, we say that $(x_1,y_1)\leq (x_2,y_2)$ if $y_2>y_1$ or $y_2=y_1$ and $x_2\geq x_1$ (we first compare the second coordinates and if they agree, we compare the first ones).

In the order topology here, it's true that a sequence $(z_n,w_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges if and only if $w_n$ is eventually constant, and $z_n$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$. If you want something to get started, try proving this last fact.

Comment: correction: the subbase are the upper and lower sets, the intervals are in the derived base. We cannot suffice with intervals when there is a min or a max. This topology is only the most usual one for linear orders. Partial orders have other natural topologies too.

Comment: If $X$ has a top element or a bottom element, they will not be in any member of your subbase.

Comment: Right. I guess there's also something about the cardinality of the set.

Comment: No, the cardinality is irrelevant. Why do you think that?

Comment: Well, say $X=\{x\},$ then the only lower set and the only upper set are both empty.

Comment: No problem, there are also no open intervals BTW, but the generated topology is still the unique one on a singleton.

Comment: That's definitely true, yeah.

Comment: What is simple order relation (mentioned in Munkres) ?

Comment: @HarryWilliamson see paragraph 3, under order relations (p24).