# The Order of sets like $\mathbb Q$ and Justification of the Number Line

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, ordered-fields

Rudin, in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, defines an ordered set $S$ as a set with a relation such that

> (i)  If $x\in S$ the one and only one of the statements $$x<y,\,\,\,\,x=y\,\,\,\,\,y<x$$
>   is true.
>
> (ii) For $x,y,z\in S$, if $x<y,$ and $y<z$, then $x<z$.

He also gives the axioms for an ordered field (field axioms, including axioms for (+) and ($\bullet$) for inequalities).

My question is: Are the above two properties of (<) all we need for a set to geometrically represent it as points on a line such that for any point $x$ if a point $y$ is to the right of $x$ then $x<y$? Are all ordered sets ($S$,<) isomorphic if say $S$ is countable? Can all sets that satisfy $(i)-(ii)$ be put into a line similar to $\mathbb Q$?

If not, what other order properties are needed to justify a linear graph of the the rational or real numbers?

:Edit: What field of study would the justification of the number line be? Topology? Order Theory?

Comment: Are you asking for a classification of all linearly ordered sets that are isomorphic to subsets of the real numbers $\mathbb R$ with respect to the standard ordering on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Kinda. I'm asking what properties of ordered sets are required to justify putting them into a number line.  Can a partially ordered set be put in a number line?  Does it need more properties?

Comment: Partially ordered sets are an entirely different topic, I would not add more to your question by including them.

Comment: Anyway, you should decide what mathematical question you really want to ask. As currently stated, your question is rather vague. That's why I asked you my question above, in the hopes that your question could be made more precise (to avoid it being closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're touching on the field of "order-theory" (which has connections to model theory, topology  and set theory, mostly). The axioms describe a (strict) linear order, and the standard examples are $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ which almost anyone doing mathematics encounters somehow. All these have a standard linear order associated with them.

In general we consider two linearly ordered sets $(X,<_X)$ and $(Y,<_Y)$ to be *order-isomorphic* when there exists a bijection $f: X \to Y$ such that $$\forall x,x' \in X: x <_X  x' \iff f(x) <_Y f(x')$$

and such sets are considered to have "the same order structure". Abstractly we have a partition into linearly ordered sets into "equivalence class" of this with the same order, and such an equivalence class is called an "order type". We can talk about the order type of $\mathbb{N}$, as all linear orders that are order isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ (intuitively: start with a minimal element, and add a unique successor for every element, and don't stop (or unit we first have an infinite number of elements). A boring example: the even numbers in their inherited order are the same order type as $\mathbb{N}$, and some thought will show that the same holds for all infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. For every finite number $n$ there is a unique order type of linear orders of type $n$, but this is definitely **not** the case for countable sets.

Some order properties for some countable orders that can serve to show they're not order-isomorphic:

- $\mathbb{N}$ has a minimum, $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ do not.
- $\mathbb{Z}$ has the property that every point has two neighbours (a right neighbour of $x$ is an $x^+$ such that $x < x^+$ but not $x'$ exists with $x < x' < x^+$; a left neighbour is the same but smaller), while $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have that property  and in $\mathbb{N}$, $0$ has no left neighbour.
- $\mathbb{Q}$ is order dense ($\forall x,y \in X: (x < y) \to (\exists z \in X: x < z < y)$ but the orders $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are not (see previous property).

It turns out that the order type of $\mathbb{Q}$ is special: If $(X,<)$ is a countable linearly ordered set, and $X$ is order dense and has no maximum or minimum, then $X$ is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, and moreover any countable linearly ordered set is order-ismorphic to some subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (in the inherited order from the rationals). So all countable can certainly be embedded into a number line (namely $\Bbb Q$), but for larger cardinals this need not be true, I believe. For a little more on order types see [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type), e.g.

The well-ordered (meaning: every non-empty subset has a minimum) linear orders get a special study in set theory. They are uniquely represented by so-called ordinal numbers. They form the basis for cardinal numbers.

And $\Bbb Q$ can be so-called "order-completed" (there are still gaps in it: sets with upper bound but with no least upper bound) and it turns out the order type of the order-completion of $\Bbb Q$ is exactly $\Bbb R$ and in analysis this order compeleteness is used all over the place.

A standard work on linear order theory see the book "Linear Orderings", by Rosenstein. You can define addition and multiplication of order types e.g. Any linearly ordered set has a natural topology too (in fact for all four examples in the first paragraph, their natural topologies are in fact the order topology), that I recently talked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3361893/4280), if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not exactly sure what you mean by “isomorphic,” but I assume that $(S_1, <_1)$ and $(S_2,<_2)$ are said to be “isomorphic” if there exists a bijection $f:S_1\mapsto S_2$ such that $x_1 <_1 y_1\iff f(x_1) <_2 f(x_2)$ for all $x_1,y_1\in S_1$ and $x_2,y_2\in S_2$. I also assume that these orderings $<_1, <_2$ satisfy $x<y\iff y>x$.

I under this definition, not all countable sets $S$ are isomorphic. For example, there cannot exist any such order-preserving bijection from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$, or for that matter, from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Z$.

We can intuitively prove that no such “isomorphism” $f:\mathbb N\mapsto\mathbb Z$ exists because for all $n$ in $\mathbb Z$ under the natural ordering, there exists $n’$ such that $n’ < n$, while this is not the case for $\mathbb N$.

We can also intuitively prove that no “isomorphism” from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Q$ exists because for all $p,q\in\mathbb Q$ satisfying $p<q$ under the natural ordering, there exists $r\in\mathbb Q$ such that $p<r<q$, but this property does not hold for $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I see. Thanks that makes sense.   On the topic of the number line, I can understand the intuitive construction of the number line for say the rational numbers (each positive rational number is geometrically its magnitude's distance away from zero to the right on the line. And similar for the negative numbers).  My main question was what properties of order are needed generally to justify a linear ordering geometrically?

Comment: @BENG What does it mean to "justify a linear ordering geometrically"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber To plot it each point on a line such that if a point C is "in between" A and B and A < B then A < C < B.  "In between" meaning that in an intuitive sense.  Formally you can take in between in the same sense that Hilbert did in his Foundations of Geometry.

Comment: Essentially, can we plot any linear order on a line and preserve its order?  If so, why?